# How to cast an variable with type abstract class to its subclass?

Tags: c++, class, oop, interface, abstract-class

I'm writing an interface for a method.

```
void method(Node* node);
```

The interface has the code

```
class Node {
 public:
     virtual void init(Node* a) = 0;
};
```

The sub class has the code

```
class CNode: public Node {
 public:
     void init(Node* a);
     void init(CNode* a);
}
```

In the code `CNode::init(Node* a)`, the function will try to convert `a` into `CNode`, then call `CNode::init(CNode* a)`.

I'm trying to implement it with

```
void CNode::init(Node *a) {
    CNode b = dynamic_cast<CNode *>(*a);
}
```

However, clang reported this error

> 'Node' is not a pointer

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It should be : `CNode* b = dynamic_cast<CNode*>(a);`

Comment: You can only use `dynamic_cast` on pointers, by dereferencing the ptr (`*a`) you're trying to `dynamic_cast` an object, which is what the error is saying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
void CNode::init(Node *a) {
    if (CNode *b = dynamic_cast<CNode *>(a))
        init(b);
}
```